# FFmpeg, how to embed cover art (image) to .m4a

Tags: ffmpeg, aac, mpeg-4, m4a

Is there any way to embed cover art to `m4a` files?

This one works well for `mp3` but doesn't work for `m4a`

```
ffmpeg -i tests/in.m4a -i cover.jpg -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -acodec copy \
  -id3v2_version 3 tests/out.m4a
```

Comment: Why do you use ID3 formats in MPEG4 files. These are not compatible with each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FFmpeg has an [open issue](//trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2798) on this functionality. In the meantime, covers
can be added with the [TagEditor project](//github.com/Martchus/tageditor). To add:

```
tageditor -s cover=ju.jpg --max-padding 100000 -f ki.m4a
```

To remove:

```
tageditor -s cover= --max-padding 100000 -f ki.m4a
```

Comment: It has nice GUI too :-)

Answer (score 18):

`mp4art` from `mp4v2` can also do this:

```
mp4art --add cover.jpg track.m4a
```

I tried mp4art, after adding the cover, the information from **FFmpeg** is like this:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fce82011400] stream 0, timescale not set
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '01 - Welcome To New York.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2
    title           : Welcome To New York
    artist          : Taylor Swift
    album           : 1989 (Deluxe)
    date            : 2014
    encoder         : Lavf55.48.100
    genre           : Country & Folk
    track           : 1
    disc            : 1
  Duration: 00:03:32.65, start: 0.046444, bitrate: 250 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 238 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg), 1400x1400 [SAR 72:72 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Input #1, image2, from 'Album Cover.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg), 1400x1400 [SAR 72:72 DAR 1:1], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

It seems that 1 file has 2 input formats (1 m4a, 1 image2), I think ffmpeg should be able to do the same thing by itself instead of using a separate tool to add cover image, but I haven't figure out how.

Answer (score 18):

It is possible with ffmpeg by specifying the `attached_pic` attribute on the image source via the `-disposition` parameter.

```
ffmpeg -i input.m4a -i image.jpg -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -disposition:v:1 attached_pic output.m4a
```

Tested with ffmpeg 4.2.2.

A similar command is also given as an example in the [ffmpeg docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html), however be careful that the example is for adding covers to *videos* but not audio files. The `-disposition` parameter fails silently if the wrong stream is selected.

Comment: failure: [ipod @ 0x7fd692008200] Could not find tag for codec png in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- 
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times

Comment: Adding `-id3v2_version 3` seems to be doing the trick on ffmpeg 4.4

Comment: I was having the same error as @ChaitanyaBapat and turns out the issue is in the `-disposition:v:1`. Simply replacing it with `-disposition:v:0` or even `-disposition:v` did the trick.
This led me to conclude that the mapping with `-map` is not even necessary. In other words, the following is sufficient:
`ffmpeg -i input.m4a -i image.jpg -c copy -disposition:v attached_pic output4.m4a`
Tested with ffmpeg 4.3.6.

Answer (score 3):

A little bit extended version for embedding album art with `atomicparsley`. Tested on Mac OS X. It assumes there is `folder.jpg` file in the current directory. AtomicParsley creates temp files with embedded media in the same folder. There is a flag `--overWrite` which is supposed to change this behavior, but for some reason this doesn't work for me. So we will need to remove the original files afterwards. Note, that the script will remove *all* the files which do not coontain `temp` in their filename. So be cautious (or modify the script). Finally, the script renames newly created files to remove `-temp-` part from their filenames.

```
for f in *.m4a
do
    atomicparsley "$f" --artwork folder.jpg
done
rm !(*temp*)
for f in *.m4a
do
    g=${f//-temp*./.}
    mv "$f" "$g"
done
```