# How to embed cover art into MP4 without errors?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, id3, artwork

I want to add artwork to my MP4 file. How do I do this successfully / without errors?
I've tried these methods with numerous MP4 files, none worked.
If you would like to replicate the errors / bugs, here are the sample [files](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/29plag9akl9r1/61375246) I've used for this question.

I've tried the following:

---

1. `ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -i sample.png -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -disposition:v:0 attached_pic sample_w_artwork.mp4`
   as stated by [Lukas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61015965/12308353)

with this error:

```
[mp4 @ 0000019ee4852280] Could not find tag for codec h264 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

[ffmpeg 4.2.2](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/ffmpeg-4.2.2-win64-static.zip) (Windows build by Zeranoe)

2. `atomicparsley sample.mp4 --artwork sample.png --overWrite`

with no success; [AtomicParsley](https://sourceforge.net/projects/atomicparsley/files/atomicparsley/AtomicParsley%20v0.9.0/AtomicParsley-win32-0.9.0.zip/download)

I get this message when executing the first time:

```
Started writing to temp file.
 Progress: =============================================>100%|
 Finished writing to temp file.
```

Executing the next (nth) time gives this:

```
Updating metadata...   completed.
```

3. Adding artwork through the *GUI Tag Editor* using both available versions: [i686-w64](https://github.com/Martchus/tageditor/releases/download/v3.3.6/tageditor-3.3.6-i686-w64-mingw32.exe.zip) & [x86_64-w64](https://github.com/Martchus/tageditor/releases/download/v3.3.6/tageditor-3.3.6-x86_64-w64-mingw32.exe.zip)

with no success; it creates a *sample.mp4.bak* [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4kBR.png), even though the [software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Xt8.png) says that the operation was successful

> can't insert any more links, because I got too little rep apparently

4. Mp3tag (mp3tag.de/en)

with no success; I can successfully add the image as a cover, but it's not visible in the File Explorer. After saving it says *Saved tag in 1 of 1 files.* The [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs3ik.png) can been seen in Mp3tag though as if it's applied.

5. Tag&Rename (softpointer.com)

with no success; same story as with Mp3tag, I can apply and it's visible in the app, but not in File Explorer.

6. mp4v2 (https:// code.google.com/archive/p/mp4v2/downloads)

`mp4tags.exe -picture sample.png sample.mp4`

with no success; it executes with no (error)message

I found it on this thread

(https:// forum.videohelp.com/threads/388025-How-to-set-the-thumbnail-of-a-video-clip).

Have used the *updated* version which is the Windows build

(https:// forum.doom9.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=14314&d=1407985798).

7. iTunes

iTunes 12.10.6.2 (Microsoft Store version)

<s>iTunes doesn't load the file into the library.</s> I can run it fine though in QuickTime Player.

I didn't notice the 'Home Videos' tab. Now I can see it in there. I tried to apply the image, and it applied it only inside iTunes... So it's still not working for me.

I tried to convert the MP4 to M4A and then adding it to iTunes. I was **finally** successfully able to change the cover and it was visible in File Explorer. But that's not what I want.

I know for a fact that it's possible, because I've seen pictures on the Internet and YT and different threads where an answer is upvoted.

8. tag

https:// github.com/b4winckler/tag

The description is: *Simple command line audio tag editor*... After having to install millions of libraries and a package manager I was stuck with the compilation of the software, followed all the steps, didn't work.

I've also tried using MP4art as suggested by a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27130727/12308353) on another issue about this. He didn't include a link to it so I went looking and found another issue about [this](https://superuser.com/q/656481/1127977). One comment recommended MP4art as well, with a link that's dead.

---

I believe I've used some other methods as well but can't think of them right now. Will update if I recall.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the command as shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54719926

Comment: Didn't work, does it work for you?

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Comment: Where do I insert it? I don't want to spend another 30 mins figuring out haha

`ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -i sample.png -map 1 -map 0 -c copy -disposition:0 attached_pic out.mp4`

Comment: It's a global option, so anywhere after ffmpeg.

Comment: Ah, yes I figured. Here's the file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/pfgy1dakha5q44s/ffmpeg-20200423-151515.log/file

Comment: The sample.mp4 on which you've run the command already has two cover images attached and the command attaches a third image.

Comment: I'm confused, how do I fix this then? When loading it into Mp3tag it doesn't show that I have a cover on it...

Comment: `ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -i sample.png -map 1 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a -c copy -disposition:v:0 attached_pic sample_w_artwork.mp4`

Comment: I still does nothing for me, does it work for you? Report: http://www.mediafire.com/file/9d656z6bln8owhp/ffmpeg-20200423-161713.log/file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [*Codec Tweak Tool*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4snnj.png) under Miscellaneous > **Thumbnails** the checkbox for .mp4 was unchecked. After checking it and saving the settings it finally showed the thumbnail.

The Tweak Tool is installed with [**K-Lite Codec Pack**](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm). There are different editions available, I use the Standard edition so I can't talk for the other ones.

Credits for finding the solution: [Furty](https://superuser.com/users/1165405/furty) from the same (copied) thread on Super User in a [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1544737/how-to-embed-cover-art-into-mp4-without-errors?noredirect=1#comment2348563_1544737)

Answer (score 2):

set `disposition` in the image.`-disposition:v:0` is mapping sample.mp4. change from 0 to 1.

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -i sample.png -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -disposition:v:1 attached_pic sample_w_artwork.mp4
```