# Adding album cover art to FLAC audio files using `ffmpeg`

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have ripped files from an audio CD I just bought. I ripped using the `Music` app on my Macbook Pro, Catalina 10.15.6 - output format was `.wav` as there was no option for `FLAC`. My plan was to change format using `ffmpeg`:

```
% ffmpeg -v
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
```

Except for the "album cover artwork" addition, the `.wav-to-.flac` conversion implemented in the short `bash` script below seems to have worked as expected:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.wav
do
echo $file 
ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i "$file" -ar 48000 -c:a flac -disposition:v AnotherLand.png -vsync 0 -c:v png "${file/%.wav/.flac}"
done
```

A script very similar to this one worked some time ago on a series of `FLAC-to-FLAC` conversions I had to do to reduce the bit depth. However, in that case, the original `FLAC` files already had the artwork embedded. Since this script produced usable audio files, I decided that I would try adding the artwork with a second `ffmpeg` command.

I did some research, which informed me that there have been issues with `ffmpeg` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798709/ffmpeg-how-to-embed-cover-art-image-to-m4a), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710992/how-to-add-album-art-with-ffmpeg/48829530), [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/iddtql/cant_add_cover_art_to_flac_file/), [4](https://superuser.com/questions/843914/embed-album-art-image-to-flac-file-with-ffmpeg)) on adding album artwork to `FLAC` files.

I have tried several commands given in the references above, but still have not found a way to add album artwork to my `FLAC` files. The following command was a [highly upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18718265/5395338), which I felt would work, but didn't:

```
% ffmpeg -i "01 Grave Walker.flac" -i ./AnotherLand.png -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -codec copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" output.flac

...


Input #0, flac, from '01 Grave Walker.flac':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:06:59.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 746 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
Input #1, png_pipe, from './AnotherLand.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 522x522, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'output.flac' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
[flac @ 0x7fb4d701e800] Video stream #1 is not an attached picture. Ignoring
Output #0, flac, to 'output.flac':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
  Stream #0:1: Video: png, rgba(pc), 522x522, q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : Album cover
      comment         : Cover (front)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)

...
```

I don't understand the error message: `Video stream #1 is not an attached picture.` It *seems* to imply that that the artwork is "attached" (*embedded* ???) in the input file, but as I've specified the artwork is a separate file, this makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `-disposition:v attached_pic`:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.flac -i image.png -map 0:a -map 1 -codec copy -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" -disposition:v attached_pic output.flac
```

Comment: That gets the job done - thanks! However, I do wish you'd clarify something for me: Your command had several options that mine didn't - i.e. your command was different from mine in more ways than the `-disposition:v attached_pic:` option. How many of those are actually needed?

Comment: @Seamus For `-map` syntax difference see [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map). You don't need `-id3v2_version`.